# Multiplying inverse matrices easily.

Tags: matrices

Okay, this is more of a confirmation question than anything:

I have been given two matrices $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$. Then the inverses of these are: $A$ and  $B$.

I need to calculate $(AB^{T})^{-1}$.

My question is can I do this?:

$$(AB^{T})^{-1}$$

$$=(A^{-1}(B^{-1})^{T})$$

$$=A^{-1}*(B^{-1})^T$$

Then I can just multiply by my given matrices instead of computing the inverses? Or did I commit some sort of error?

Comment: It is true that $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$. For the rest: $A^{-1}B^{-1}AB=\ldots$ well, *not* $I$. Perhaps if you used something similar, but not the same...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli So it would not work?

Comment: Wrong formulas usually don't.

Comment: When $A$ and $B$ don't commute you need $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$. Since you put on socks before shoes you need to take off shoes before socks.

Comment: No, the inverse of a product is the product of the inverses in the REVERSE order : $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$  But you are allowed to switch the order of operators transpose (T) and inverse ($-1$) : the transpose of the inverse is the inverse of the transpose (it suffices to think to the (theoretical !) formula describing $A^{-1}$ as resulting from cofactors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note- $$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1} $$  Except that, the rest is correct and you are supposed to this way for questions like that.
 the answer would be $$=(B^{-1})^T*A^{-1}$$

 Why Order is reversed?
Well, see this- $$AB * (AB)^{-1} = I$$ 
Now, If $$(AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$$, substituting back in the previous equation, we can't get anything. Put $$ (AB)^{-1}= B^{-1}A^{-1} $$ , we get $$AB*B^{-1}A^{-1}$$ $$\implies A*I*A^{-1} = A*A^{-1} = I$$

Comment: Can you possibly explain why the order of B and A is switched around?